# PowerShell snap-in 'AzureManagementToolsSnapin' is not installed on this computer

Tags: powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I've download a script that uses the 'AzureManagementToolsSnapin' on the first line as below:
Add-PSSnapin AzureManagementToolsSnapin

I read few blogs and downloaded the Azure Powershell CMDLets from link below:
http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/releases/view/84058

When I tried to install per given documentation on link below I'm not being able to install. It however logs the error below which I completely don't understand why:

> Installing assembly
>   'C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll'.
>   Affected parameters are:    i =     assemblypath =
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll
>   logfile =
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.InstallLog
>   logtoconsole =  An exception occurred while trying to find the
>   installers in the
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll
>   assembly. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to
>   load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information. Aborting installation for
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll.
>   Rolling back assembly
>   'C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll'.
>   Affected parameters are:    i =     assemblypath =
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll
>   logfile =
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.InstallLog
>   logtoconsole =  An exception occurred while trying to find the
>   installers in the
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll
>   assembly. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to
>   load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information. Aborting installation for
>   C:\WindowsAzure\WAPPSCmdletsBin\release\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.Powershell.dll.

Please, could someone help me understand what I'm missing. I also tried to download from below:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/

However, lots of the functions on the script I download doesn't seem to exist on windows azure powershell.

The powershell code snippet looks like below, not sure it's outdated:

```
Add-PSSnapin AzureManagementToolsSnapIn

#bla bla

Get-HostedServices -SubscriptionId $sub -Certificate $cert|Select ServiceName|

foreach {
 #Logic here
$service = $_.ServiceName

write-host $service

$deployId = (Get-HostedService $service -SubscriptionId $sub -Certificate $cert | Get-Deployment Staging).DeploymentId       

Get-DiagnosticAwareRoles -StorageAccountName $storage -StorageAccountKey $key -DeploymentId $deployId | 

foreach { 

     #DO stuff here

    }   

}



}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Codeplex site indicates that your second link is now the correct one to download from. At the bottom, under Command Line Tools, is a link for PowerShell.

I downloaded that, installed, started a new PoSH session and found that there is an Azure *module*, but no snap-in. I seem to recall reading somewhere that Microsoft is pushing everyone to migrate away from snap-ins and toward modules.

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell


ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- ----                                ----------------
Binary     Azure                               {Disable-AzureServiceProjectRemoteDesktop, Enable-AzureMemcacheRole, ...
```

Without having the script you're actually trying to execute, it's impossible to diagnose your specific issue. But you are probably working with something that is a little outdated and you'll need to switch to loading the module instead of the snap-in at the very least.

**Edit after original post edit:**

The cmdlets called in your sample don't exist in the Azure module, but `Get-AzureDeployment` probably maps to `Get-Deployment`, `Get-AzureService` *may* map to `Get-HostedServices` and `Get-AzureRole` *may* map to `Get-DiagnosticAwareRoles` - but I don't know Azure.

The short version is, if the Codeplex snap-in isn't working for you, and the official word is that you should be using the module downloaded from Microsoft (the one I refer to above), you're going to have to make some adjustments.

Comment: Please see updated powershell snippet above. Not sure if it's outdated.